# Is it possible to disable code paths with command line arguments in C++?

Tags: c++, cmdline-args

I have a debug drawing flag in my game project. This flag determines whether Box2d's DebugDraw is drawing before the end of each frame. Is it possible to use something like:

```
#ifdef 'debug drawing flag'                       
//do debug drawing
#else
//skip
```

Or would it make more sense to have an if statement to check if that value was assigned?

```
//With a single command line arg
int main(int argc, char* argv []){
    //game initialization
    .
    .
    .

    //Check if its there and set flag
    uint8_t debugDrawFlag = (argc > 0 && strcmp("debugDraw", argv[0]) == 0) ? 1 : 0
           

    .
    .
    .
    if(debugDrawFlag)
        physicsWorld->DebugDraw();


}
```

Comment: *"Is it possible to use [X]"* -- why not try it and see?

Comment: *"Or would it make more sense to [Y]"* -- First, note that this is not an exclusive "or". It is logically consistent for the first option to be possible, while at the same time the second option makes more sense. Second, making more sense tends to be a matter of opinion and also to be dependent on your desired functionality.

Comment: Definitely the first method since it automatically removes all debug code with only one flag. Also should prevent bugs in your program allowing access to the debug features.

Comment: @BRem not definitely - you may want to enable debug output at runtime, without an expensive re-compile.

Comment: You can also combine the two by having a `constexpr bool debugDraw = true` or `false` depending on the build flag. You don't *have to* put `#ifdef` all through the code.

Comment: @NeilButterworth I suppose a hybrid would be best in that case: enable/disable on command, and exclude all debug code in a release version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`#ifdef` only works at compile-time, not at runtime.

Most compilers allow you to define custom symbols on the command-line while compiling, for instance with a `-D` switch or equivalent.

So, the question comes down to - do you want to specify your drawing flag at compile-time when your app is being built, or do you want to control your drawing mode dynamically when your app is being run?  If the former, use `#ifdef`.  If the latter, use `argv`.